# JEditorPane is read only

Tags: java, macos, swing, jeditorpane

I have an application which uses a JEditorPane. I am on Mac and with Java 6 everything was without any problems (it was editable). Now, I'm running with Java 7 and the Editor-Panel is read only.
I tried to debug but as soon as I use a breakpoint anywhere it is not read only anymore. The same applies when pushing a button (which does nothing than opening a message window). While resizing the window does not have any effect.
Further, an instance of this panel is used somewhere else without any problems.

I'm running out of ideas how to figure out what goes wrong.

I tried to reproduce the error with this example. It also shows up as non-editable but I am not sure at all whether this is connected at all. As I have swt-dependencies in my plugin, I need to use the swt/awt bridge to run the example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

final Display display = new Display();
final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
shell.setText("undo-edit-panel");

Composite myComp = new Composite(shell, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);

java.awt.Frame fileTableFrame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(myComp);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
fileTableFrame.add(panel);


JEditorPane edit = new JEditorPane();
edit.setText("some text");
//Put the editor pane in a scroll pane.
JScrollPane editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(edit);
editorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
editorScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 145));
editorScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));

panel.add(editorScrollPane, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

myComp.pack();

shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
}
display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a threading issue.

Comment: To debug: unwire it from any Listener and/or special window handling code. It could be something simple as a `repaint` at the wrong spot. You could also make a tiny application to reconstruct the problem.

Comment: it seems that I could solve the issue. the component is part of a JDialog which has been created with a wrong owner window. It is editable now.